# Python stops running when opening Jupyter Notebook (2020)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

When I try to open a Jupyter Notebook, I get the message of "Python has stopped working":

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version:  3.7.4150.1013
  Application Timestamp:    5d4e032a
  Fault Module Name:    kernel32.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.0.6002.19623
  Fault Module Timestamp:   56ec4631
  Exception Code:   40000015
  Exception Offset: 00000000000166cd
  OS Version:   6.0.6002.2.2.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    10250
  Additional Information 1: 7646
  Additional Information 2: 6f5640bd2d85ee936d3105b34d49bf70
  Additional Information 3: 629f
  Additional Information 4: be6e536085ea87767818ff4fbd73b729
```

Steps to Reproduce:

1) Open Jupyter Notebook (from command prompt or Anaconda Navigator)

2) Open a notebook from http://localhost:8888/tree

I have Windows Vista Home Premium 64-bit and Anaconda Navigator 1.9.12.
Python works perfectly on command prompt and text editor.
Please help.

Comment: How are you running the notebook?

Comment: well, I see `kernel32.dll' and your Windows is 64-bit, so maybe this is the problem

Comment: @AMC 1) Open Jupyter Notebook (from command prompt or Anaconda Navigator)

2) Open a notebook from http://localhost:8888/tree